# How to parse XML files in a folder in to map String,List<String>

Tags: xml, parsing, dictionary, groovy

I'm trying to parse multiple XML files in a folder and retrieve from each file a map of String, List. And I have a problem separating the values.

// ### XML File structure example

```
 <fields>
    <fullName>DandbCompanyId</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>Lookup</type>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>Description</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>DunsNumber</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>Fax</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>Industry</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>Picklist</type>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>IsCustomerPortal</fullName>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>IsPartner</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
<listViews>
    <fullName>AllAccounts</fullName>
    <filterScope>Everything</filterScope>
    <label>All Accounts</label>
</listViews>
<listViews>
    <fullName>MyAccounts</fullName>
    <filterScope>Mine</filterScope>
    <label>My Accounts</label>
</listViews>
```

// #### This what i have

```
String srcPath = this.args[0];
def objFolder = new File(srcPath + '/objects')
if(!objFolder || !objFolder.isDirectory()) {
    println " ####  ERROR: ${objFolder} doesn't exist or is not a folder"
    return
} else {
    println " ####  Path is correct! Checking objects"
}

def objMap = [:]

def xs = new XmlSlurper()

objFolder.eachFile { file ->
    objMap.put(file.getName().split("\\.")[0], xs.parse(file).fields.fullName.each{
        it.@fullName
    })
};

objMap.each { k,v -> println v}
```

// ### And this is the output

```
DescriptionIsAlohaSupportedIsLightningSupportedNameOwnerIdStartingContext

IndustryOwnership
AllocationIdAmountBudgetIdChannelPartnerIdDescriptionOwnerIdRequestIdStatusTitle
ScorecardIdTargetEntityId

ActivityAllocationIdAmountBudgetIdCampaignIdChannelPartnerIdDescriptionDesiredOutcomeOwnerIdRequestedAmountStatusTitleTotalApprovedFcsTotalReimbursedFcs
CategoriesStatus

CapturedAngleContentDocumentIdImageAlternateTextImageClassImageClassObjectTypeImageTitleImageUrlImageViewTypeIsActiveName
Role
```

What I'm aiming to achieve in the result is:

locationId, Amount, BudgetId, Channel

So it should look like a list of String (in map it will be value)

Comment: Can you try changing `xs.parse(file).fields.fullName.each{
        it.@fullName
    }` to `xs.parse(file).fields.fullName*.text()`

Comment: Thanks!!!! It finally worked, i actually tried everything i could find for the past 2 days

Comment: Yay!  I've added an explanation as an answer below 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues with what you were trying.

The first was using `each` which performs an action on each item in a collection, but it returns the original collection (not the result of the action -- for that, you need `collect`)

The second was that `it.@fullName` would return the attribute `fullName` on the tag (ie: if you had `<node fullName="something">...</node>`) whereas you just need the `text()` of the node

So the following would have worked:

```
xs.parse(file).fields.fullName.collect { it.text() }
```

But in Groovy, we can shorten this `collect` to use the spread-operator `*`, which give us the shorter:

```
xs.parse(file).fields.fullName*.text()
```

Have fun!